# How can i Fetch string value from sentence?

Tags: java, android

i want to fetch the IMPS Ref no. from string 
How can i do this? My Method of fetching is

```
// I want to fetch it with IMPS Ref. No.
String Result="Your A/c No. XXXXXXXX2335 is debited for Rs. 20 on 04-10-16 and A/c linked to mobile 9818685050 credited " +
                    "( IMPS Ref No. 627814178257 )";

if(Result.indexOf("IMPS Ref No.") > 0)
{
    System.out.println(Result.indexOf("IMPS Ref No."));
    String[] result=Result.split("\\(");
    System.out.println(result[1]);
    String imps=result[1];
    String numberOnly= imps.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
    System.out.println(numberOnly);
 }
```

Comment: try this trick, get string from `(` to `)` . this may helps you.

Comment: What is your code issue? Seems to work fine